# How to read several objects FileInputStream?

Tags: java, file

First of all, the variables are in Portuguese, but does not influence the code understanding.

Here is my code:

```
public ArrayList<Produto> recuperarProdutos(){
    ArrayList<Produto> produtos = new ArrayList<>();
    Produto p = new Produto();

    ObjectInputStream leitorObj = null;
    FileInputStream leitorArquivo = null;
    try {
        leitorArquivo = new FileInputStream("files\\Produtos.ser");
        leitorObj = new ObjectInputStream(leitorArquivo);
        p = (Produto)leitorObj.readObject();
        produtos.add(p);
    } catch(EOFException e) {
    try {
        leitorArquivo.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {
            if (leitorArquivo != null) leitorArquivo.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    return produtos;
}
```

this code will add at my ArrayList just the first Produto object that there are in my file. This is not what I want, is there any EOF in Java to do a loop and read each object ?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
while ((p = (Produto)leitorObj.readObject()) != null) {
    produtos.add(p);
}
```